# Regex replace operation if exist in java

Tags: java, regex, string, intellij-idea, replace

**IS:**

```
String: "DARTH WEDR DR MRS"
Regex: "(.*?DR)\\s(-|MRS?|MI?SS?)?$"
```

This regex operation cant remove MRS and leave only DR.
[image]

**SHOULD:**

```
String: "DARTH WEDR DR MRS".replaceAll("(.*?DR)\\s(-|MRS?|MI?SS?)?$", "");
Output: "DARTH WEDR DR"
```

Abbreviation is always at the end, but some names can have abbreviation in their names, so it should be `<space> DR <space>` to read at the end to escape the problem with abbreviation in the names.

**EXAMPLE:**

```
BRUCE WAYNE MR
GAL GADOT DR MS
GOD ZILADR DR MRS
```

---

Im out of ideas. Any idea?

Comment: Replace with `$1`. Probably, you also want to replace `\\s(-|MRS?|MI?SS?)?$` with `(?:\\s+(?:-|MRS?|MI?SS?))?$` and add `\\s` before `DR`. See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/6ORg4a/1).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks, that worked as I wished. Yeah $1 forgot about that, my fault.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using

```
.replaceAll("(.*?\\sDR)(?:\\s+(?:-|MRS?|MI?SS?))?$", "$1");
                 ^^^   ^^^   ^ ^^              ^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/6ORg4a/1)

**NOTES**:

- Since you need to match `DR` enclosed with whitespaces, `\s` is added before `DR`
- The whole trailing part is optional, so the whitespace must also be optional. `(?:\s+(?:-|MRS?|MI?SS?))?` matches 1 or 0 occurrences of 1+ whitespaces followed with `-`, `MR`, `MRS`, `MS`, `MSS`,`MIS` or `MISS`
- To keep the starting text, replace with the backreference to Group 1.